# Why does notmuch ignore my wildcards?

Tags: notmuch

My read of the [notmuch search documentation](https://notmuchmail.org/manpages/notmuch-search-terms-7/) suggests that I should be able to use wildcards in searches, but that doesn't seem to be the case. For instance, I have my mail archives organized into folders by year. If I search for...

```
notmuch search folder:INBOX.Archives.*
```

I get no results, but if I search for a specific year, I get what I expected -- the list of messages in that folder:

```
notmuch search folder:INBOX.Archives.2007
```

Similarly, `tag:inbo*` gets nothing. `tag:inbox` gets plenty.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [notmuch-search-terms(7)](https://notmuchmail.org/manpages/notmuch-search-terms-7/) the syntax for searching by folder is:

`folder:<maildir-folder> or folder:/<regex>/`

The search term has to be regex which is enclosed in slashes.

Try following expression:

`notmuch search folder:/INBOX\.Archives\..*/`

Comment: Fixing the expression because the tab-completion gave me the latter and it worked fine for searching archives.

Comment: I'm glad to hear my answer helped :)

Comment: LOL. TBH it really didn't -- this question is three years old. But since it didn't have an answer yet I went ahead and tested your solution to confirm it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You're right, the question is old. It waited and matured here for me :)